# select query to get those result where for every unique value of column 3, column 2 has bothval1 and val2

Tags: mysql

```
MEMO    TYPE    ID

2442    11  52
33658   4   52
823     6   56
825     4   56
826     7   56
85      4   57
3298    7   57
87      4   141
377     7   141
88      4   142
378     7   142
98      1   143
99      2   143
194     7   143
7586    5   143
1451    4   143
7781    6   143
3252    4   167
3249    6   167
3915    7   167
13666   5   167
115     4   168
9253    9   168
9254    10  168
138     1   194
139     2   194
1951    4   194
8650    7   194
8191    6   197
8192    7   197
9687    8   197
9930    9   197
```

I need to select those records from above table where for every unique value in column 'ID', column 'TYPE' have value 6 and 7 both.
Result of this select query would be as below:

```
MEMO    TYPE    ID
 823    6   56
 826    7   56
7781    6   143
 194    7   143
3249    6   167
3915    7   167
8191    6   197
8192    7   197
```

I hope this data is not too much.

Comment: "I want" is not how questions are supposed to be asked here...

Comment: This is just a part of a table containing more than 35K records. Column 'TYPE' contains many other values apart from 6 and 7. It has 36 other columns.

Comment: Please see this link for guidance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @HyperAnthony : I've read the link and modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.* 
from your_table t
inner join
(
    select id, min(type) as mint, max(type) as maxt
    from your_table
    where type in (6,7)
    group by id
    having count(distinct type) = 2
) x on x.id = t.id and t.type in (x.maxt,x.mint)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aebe/13)

Comment: This is just a part of a table containing more than 35K records. Column 'TYPE' contains many other values apart from 6 and 7.

Comment: This helps but partially. The resultset contains only unique ids i.e. ids are not repeated.
It would be really great if resultset can be in the form I mentioned in the question.
Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate this.